# PDCurses set key repeat delay to 0

Tags: c++, curses, pdcurses

Using PDCurses, how do I set the key repeat delay to 0, so when a key is pressed, `getch()` returns the character every frame, without any delay when a key is held down?

Comment: This may help: according to the [documentation](https://pdcurses.org/docs/MANUAL.html#getch), it seems there is a `nodelay` mode.

Comment: According to the docs `nodelay` means that when no key is being pressed down, `getch` returns ERR, without no delay, the program will hang until a key is pressed, meaning it stops the program.